# Wordpress - subcategories can be accessed by different permalinks. How to fix?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I ran into a problem in wordpress that subcategories are accessible at 2 different urls. In the first case, a base category is included into the url structure. In the second case an url does not contain a base url.

For example, my project has category "*Malaysia*" and subcategory "*Borneo*". So I can access a subcategory "Borneo" via urls:

1. https://life-thai.com/category/malaysia/borneo/
2. https://life-thai.com/category/borneo/

How to leave only 1 url to prevent duplicating?

The permalink structure on the website has the following structure: `domain.com/%postname%/`